# Implementing Admob. Game with one activity

Tags: android, admob

I've been following this tutorial: http://www.kilobolt.com/day-6-the-android-game-framework-part-ii.html , I've finished my game and now I want to add AdMob. I managed to add Intersticial Ad in the AndroidGame class(code for AndroidGame class and other classes can be found in the tutorial mentioned above). Ad is shown when the onResume() method is called. That's not really the thing I need. I think it would be better to show ad more often. It would be nice to show intersticial or banner when the game is paused or on Game Over screen.

So recently I found this: http://forum.kilobolt.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=65&p=528&hilit=admob#p528

This is something I need but it does not work. I tried to fix it with no result. My question is: how to fix this code? Or is there a better way to add ads?

My code is the same so posting it makes no sense in my opinion. I will post it if it's needed.

Edit:

AdMobHandler

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
public class AdMobHandler extends Handler {
private AdView adView=null;public AdMobHandler(AdView adView) {
super();
this.adView = adView;
}@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
if ( adView.getVisibility() != msg.what ) {
adView.setVisibility(msg.what);
}
}
}
```

AndroidGame

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.kilobolt.robotgame.AdMobHandler;
import com.kilobolt.helper.FileIO;
import com.kilobolt.helper.Game;
import com.kilobolt.helper.Graphics;public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game {
public static AdRequest adRequest;
public static AdRequest adRequest2;
public static AdMobHandler admobHandler;
public static AdMobHandler admobHandler2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
int frameBufferWidth = isPortrait ? 480 : 800;
int frameBufferHeight = isPortrait ? 800 : 480;
Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth
/ getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight
/ getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(this);
audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
screen = getInitScreen();RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
layout.addView(renderView);
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("myid");
adView2 = new AdView(this);
adView2.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView2.setAdUnitId("myid");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
layout.addView(adView, params);
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
layout.addView(adView2, params);setContentView(layout);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
adView2.loadAd(adRequest);
AdMobHandler admobHandler = new AdMobHandler(adView);
AdMobHandler admobHandler2 = new AdMobHandler(adView2);
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,
"MyGame");
admobHandler.sendEmptyMessage(View.GONE);
admobHandler2.sendEmptyMessage(View.GONE);
}
@Override
public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
if (screen == null)
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Screen must not be null");
this.screen.pause();
this.screen.dispose();
screen.resume();
screen.update(0);
this.screen = screen;
}

}
```

Part of GameScreen

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
public class GameScreen extends Screen {
public static AdMobHandler admobHandler;
public static AdMobHandler admobHandler2;
private AdView adView;
private AdView adView2;@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {
List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();

if (state == GameState.Ready) {
updateReady(touchEvents);
AndroidGame.admobHandler.sendEmptyMessage(View.GONE);
AndroidGame.admobHandler2.sendEmptyMessage(View.VISIBLE);
}
if (state == GameState.Running) {
updateRunning(touchEvents, deltaTime);
AndroidGame.admobHandler.sendEmptyMessage(View.GONE);
AndroidGame.admobHandler2.sendEmptyMessage(View.VISIBLE);
}
if (state == GameState.Paused) {
updatePaused(touchEvents);
AndroidGame.admobHandler.sendEmptyMessage(View.VISIBLE);
AndroidGame.admobHandler2.sendEmptyMessage(View.VISIBLE);
}
if (state == GameState.GameOver) {
updateGameOver(touchEvents);
AndroidGame.admobHandler.sendEmptyMessage(View.GONE);
AndroidGame.admobHandler2.sendEmptyMessage(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: for the purpose of longevity you need to post it, so as long this question is alive your problem with the codes are alive. and also help your answerers answer you.

Comment: You should post your code because the linked resource may disappear, be moved, etc. Also to help others with similar problems find it